# How to calculate/plot molecular orbitals with XTB?

Tags: orbitals, xtb

I started playing with the [XTB program](https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb) (XTB is developed by Prof. Grimme group's, is based on tight binding and uses the [GFN force field](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gfnff.html)).

**Question: How can I calculate/plot the molecular orbitals?**
I just found the inputs needed to calculate but not how to export in order to plot.

Comment: you can try the alternative DFTB+ implementation, whoch then allow you to use the toolset of that program and let you generate eg cube files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the `--molden` flag should give you a molden file with the orbitals.